# Error:$controller:ctrlreg A controller with this name is not registered

Tags: angularjs

I try to register a controller depending on the module of navbarController,but the navbarController is undefined

```
use strict'

define(['navbarController'], function (navbarController) {

    var myApp = angular.module('CustomersApp', []);
     console.log(navbarController);//undefined
    (function (app) {
        "use strict";
        app.controller('navbarController', navbarController);

    })(myApp);
})

navbarController.js
define(function () {

    var vm = this,
     appTitle = 'Customer Management';
    vm.isCollapsed = false;
    vm.appTitle = appTitle;
    console.log("controller")
})
```

Comment: Are u writing unit tests?

Comment: Nope,buddy. I just want to create a controller which depends on the module of navbarController. It seems weird but I do not know where

Comment: In additon, I used RequireJS to manage my module and I make the navbarController a module to inject the app.js